# Flutter ListView - Hide Scrollbar

Tags: flutter, listview, scrollbar

While `ListView` has a scrollbar and you can add a `Scrollbar` to other scrollable widgets; Is it possible to hide the scrollbar on a `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong `ListView` does not have a `scrollbar` per default, but if it has, you can use `ListView.Builder` instead, here is an example:

```
   Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {

      // backing data
      final europeanCountries = ['Albania', 'Andorra', 'Armenia', 'Austria', 
        'Azerbaijan', 'Belarus', 'Belgium', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Bulgaria',
        'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland',
        'France', 'Georgia', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Iceland', 'Ireland',
        'Italy', 'Kazakhstan', 'Kosovo', 'Latvia', 'Liechtenstein', 'Lithuania',
        'Luxembourg', 'Macedonia', 'Malta', 'Moldova', 'Monaco', 'Montenegro',
        'Netherlands', 'Norway', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Russia',
        'San Marino', 'Serbia', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 
        'Switzerland', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine', 'United Kingdom', 'Vatican City'];

      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: europeanCountries.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(europeanCountries[index]),
          );
        },
      );

    }
```